# Quickest way to implement a new interface member in many classes?

Tags: c#, .net

Do you know a quick way to implement method(s) from an Interface to a Class. If yes, how can you do it?

Situation : I have an Interface used by over 15 concrete classes. I added a new method and I need to implement this new method in all concrete class.

**Update**

All my concrete class implement the interface and all the method fine. Later, I add a new method in the interface. To be able to compile, I need to implement the new method in all class. I do not want to go 1 by 1 on each class to implement the method. Is there a way, like "Right clicking the new method" in the interface that will go in all concrete class and all automaticly the new method. This way I will not have to open all class?

Comment: Is the interface IMPLEMENTED or USED by 15 classes ?

Comment: I have Resharper 3.0. I have see Safe delete that let me take out a method, but haven't see anything to "add".

Comment: Yeah the class Implement the interface already. I have modified the Interface so now I need to open all class to implements the new method.

Comment: add "some class: some interface" manually, then use quick-fix actions to automatically generate method stubs

Comment: Something in my gut says an interface being implemented by 15 classes means either the interface is too general (ie. needs segregating into multiple interfaces) or there is a need for at least 1 abstract base class.

Comment: I am not asking how to implement an interface. I would like to be able to change the concrete class faster. I am asking if someone have an idea. If you do not, I understand... aku answer is good since it's faster than checking 1 by 1 concrete class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you mentioned that you have ReSharper installed, here some way to quickly implement this:

- Use "Find Usages Advanced" with
  "Implementations" checkbox checked
- For each class use quick action
  "Implement members"

Also you can use "[solution wide analysis](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_analysis.html#Solution-Wide_Analysis)" feature of ReSharper - it will quickly find all classes that don't implement this new method

**EDIT:**

Finally I found a *really* quick way:

- Save method signature in clipboard.
- Position cursor on Boo in IFoo
  interface (notice code error - empty code block, this is intentional).
- Right click and choose Refactor->"Push Members down"
- Select needed classes in the shown dialog box and click Next.
- Restore method signature from clipboard

```
internal interface IFoo
{
    void Boo()
    {
    }
}

class Boo:IFoo
{
}

class Foo: IFoo
{
}
```

Comment: This is the only answer for the moment that look "fast". Thx aku.

Comment: ReSharper is an amazing tool, eh?  You *did*, however, steal my answer ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Provide an abstract base class with a default implementation, and then have all your concrete classes inherit that abstract class.

Comment: Don't know why this was -1 ... that's the right answer. Unless you were looking for "copy and paste it".

Comment: Maybe Daok was looking for an IDE help, rather than a code solution.

Comment: I cannot inherit abstract class. Class can inherit only 1 class and many Interface. I am more searching a way to do it, see Aku answer. This solution is not what I search.

Comment: Your abstract class could also inherit anything else you need.

Comment: Not all these concretes classes inherit the same class. So I would have to create many Abstract Class. This will become bloaty for no real reason.

Answer (score 1):

With Resharper you can select your new interface member (put your cursor on it) and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or click on the hammer icon then

1. Implement in derived classes
2. Implement member in all above types

Answer (score 0):

yes,

immplement the interface class in each of the 15 classes.  Example:

```
public class MyClass:MyInteface{

}
```

afterwards, Hover over the first letter of the interface name, and select from dropdown "Explicitly implement interface ".

I am assuming you are using Visual Studio.

Comment: I know that way... I am searching something faster.

Comment: While this is a nice way to stub out the class functions, the IDE will add an exception ("This functionality has not yet been implemented" or something) to the function. Make sure that you remove this if your class is not going to do anything with the added function or you'll have problems later.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Now you can do this using the option (not very visible) in the image (sorry for the VS in spanish:) )  All the classes that inherit from this Interface will have the interface autoimplemented.

[image]